# Creating a Chart using JSON, JQUERY and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to populate a chart using JSON data which has been retrieved from a Database using PHP. I have done some research before coming to stackoverflow. I am using anychart's bar chart formatting. Below is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['myData'])){
    $integer = $_POST['myData'];


    if ($integer === "3"){
    
    include 'db_connection.php';
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $return_arr3 = array();
    $query = "SELECT Wins, Loses, Draws FROM `record` WHERE Year = '2019/2020'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $wins = $row['Wins'];
        $loses = $row['Loses'];
        $draws = $row['Draws'];

        $return_arr3[] = array("Wins" => $wins,
                              "Loses" => $loses,
                             "Draws" => $draws);
        echo($return_arr3);
}

    // Encoding array in JSON format
    echo json_encode($return_arr3);
}
```

Then here is my HTML code.

```
<div id="minutes_popup" class="popupcontainer">
  <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-data-adapter.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

Finally, here is my JavaScript code.

```
$("#minutes").click(function(){
alert("Button works"); 

$("#minutes_popup").toggle();   

var integer = $("#minutes").attr("name");
alert("integer: " + integer);

$.ajax('includes/test.php', {
    type: 'POST',  // http method
    data: {myData: integer},// data to submit
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    anychart.data.loadJsonFile("includes/test.php", function (response) {
        // create a chart and set loaded data
        chart = anychart.bar(response);
        chart.container("minutes_popup");
        chart.draw();
    });
    });
    }
});
});
```

This code doesn't work for some reason unknown to me. No errors appear on the console and the data is echoed to the console in this format:

[{"Wins":"34","Loses":"19","Draws":"10"}]

However, a bar chart is not being created.

If anyone could tell me how to fix my code, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is the issue? You just mention "stupid problem". For future reference, always describe your problem and add any errors and debugging efforts into the question.

Comment: One "stupid problem" I see is: `$query = "SELECT Wins, Loses, Draws FROM \`record\` WHERE Year = "2019/2020"";`. You can't mix quotes like that. What you think is the opening quote of `2019/2020` is actually closing the `SELECT` opening quote. Use single quotes for the value or escape the double quotes around the value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have changed that code. Now, the issue which I have is that the array is being displayed on the console however, it isn't being using in the chart? Instead I just see a white screen. Any idea why this is ?

Comment: Check your AJAX response (developer toolbar > network tab > click on the request > click Response) for any further errors. Also check the console tab to see any client errors. A blank page could be a ton of things.

Comment: I have checked the console and the network tab. No errors. The data is being retrieved and displayed in the network section. But also my fault in explaining my error.The white screen is just a pop-up box where the graph is supposed to be displayed.

Comment: I have just seen that my test.php is being retrieved twice. One has all my data which I need on it and then the one after that is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226245/discussion-between-sam-west-and-el-vanja).